# htaccess rewrite, adding php for index only

Tags: php, .htaccess

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo $url;
```

If I put my url as /anything I get 'anything' echo'd, but if I put my url as /index my echo is 'index.php'
Why is this?

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: Literally what you can see above.

Comment: Try changing your pattern to thing **^((?!index.php).+)$**

Comment: Yes, Does it work?

Comment: No, it gives Undefined index: url for index

Comment: Is **/index** an existent file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule looks fine but my guess is /index.php is your directory Index handler. You have Multiviews turned on on your server and that is why Index is changing to /index.php

Try adding the following line at the top of your htaccess

```
Options -Multiviews
```